# Dynamic Linq Search using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions

Tags: c#, linq

I use the great NinjaNye.SearchExtensions in c# core mvc. That works perfect but I would need dynamic search options. Is that possible? Or do I need several if else blocks?

I have this linq

```
return tmpIQueryable
     .Where(c => data.Contains(c.id) && c.enddate > DateTime.Now.Date && c.startdate < untildate)
     .Include(c => c.DataContainer)

     .Search(x => x.title.ToLower(),
             x => x.manu.ToLower(),
             x => x.short.ToLower(),
             x => x.long.ToLower(),
             x => x.detail.ToLower())
     .ContainingAll(searchlist)
```

I have boolean variables where to search in (user can choose in GUI with checkboxes where he want to search in) - search_in_title, search_in_manu, search_in_short, search_in_long, search_in_detail. How can I dynamic search in a field or not without in this case 5^2 if/else for different linq.

Thanks a lot
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

You may add `.Where` clause multiple times:

```
if (searchInTitleChecked)
    tmpIQueryable = tmpIQueryable.Where(r => r.Title.ToLower() == title);  

if (searchInShortChecked)
    tmpIQueryable = tmpIQueryable.Where(r => r.Short.ToLower() == short);
```

This is just example of Linq, but not NinjaNye.SearchExtensions. If it's not helpful, please ignore.

However you may try the same here:

```
if (searchInTitleChecked)
    tmpIQueryable = tmpIQueryable.Search(x => x.title.ToLower());  

if (searchInShortChecked)
    tmpIQueryable = tmpIQueryable.Search(x => x.short.ToLower());

tmpIQueryable = tmpIQueryable.ContainingAll(searchlist);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast reply! Unfortunately it seems not to work with the NinjaNye.SearchExtensions in that way :( I get some errors if I try this solution.  
I use this component because its cool to search flexible on one or several searchkeywords in a list - in all fields.